# \citenum with square brackets

Tags: spacing, citing, natbib

I am using the superscript citation style and sometimes in the text I need to print the citation number is square brackets like `[6]`. I read I could use `\citenum` but `[\citenum{myref}]` leaves some big space before the number `[ 6]`.
 Is there anyway I can achive this nicely?

EDIT. These are my `natbib` options:

```
 \usepackage[square, comma, sort&compress,authoryear]{natbib}
 \bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{s}{}{;}
```

Comment: Please consider to upvote helpful answers to your older questions (this has to be done separately from accepting them).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I will do as per the other post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following attempt (a redefinition of `\citenum`) removes most (?) of the spacing. Sorry for not providing a real solution, but the `natbib` internals are nothing one wants to delve into.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[square,comma,sort&compress,authoryear]{natbib}
\bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{s}{}{;}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\citenum
   {\begingroup
%      \NAT@swatrue\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@parfalse\let\textsuperscript\NAT@spacechar% DELETED
     \NAT@swatrue\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@parfalse\let\textsuperscript\relax% NEW
     \NAT@citexnum[][]}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text \citep{A01}.

[\citenum{A01}]

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that inserting a couple of negative spaces (`\!`) works fine. e.g.

```
These are outlined in an excellent review by Foo [\!\!\citenum{Foo2012}]; however, we choose to...
```

Perhaps this is not a very elegant solution in terms of understanding the problem, but it is concise!

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest way was to just to into the natbib.sty. Copy it first to 
your local latex folder, e.g.

```
 ~/texmf/tex/latex/.
```

Find the line

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\citenum
```

and replace the part

```
@parfalse
```

with

```
@partrue
```

done.

Comment: Of course that I expected everyone to know, but I edit my answer anyways to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I know you are using natbib's options; but, have you tried to use revtex as your documentclass? Using the same example as lockstep, I can write:

```
\documentclass[aip]{revtex4-1}    
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
@misc{B01,
  author = {Author, B.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Beta},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Some text with superscript citation.~\citep{A01}

Another text with in-line citation.~[\onlinecite{B01}]

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's quite a substantial change to suggest using a specific document class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.